# Concate 2 dfs by a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dfs

```
import pandas as pd
list_columns = ['Number', 'Name', 'Age']
list_data = [
    [121, 'John', 25],
    [122, 'Sam', 26]
    ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)

   Number  Name  Age
0     121  John   25
1     122   Sam   26
```

and

```
list_columns = ['Number', 'Name', 'Age']
list_data = [
    [121, 'John', 31],
    [122, 'Sam', 29],
    [123, 'Andrew', 28]
    ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)

   Number    Name  Age
0     121    John   31
1     122     Sam   29
2     123  Andrew   28
```

In the end I want to take the missing values from df2 and add them into df1 bassed on the column **Number**.

In the above case in df1 I am missing only the Number 123, and I want to move only the data from this line to df1, so it will lok like

```
|Number|Name  | Age|
| 121  |John  | 25 |
| 122  |Sam   | 26 |
| 123  |Andrew| 28 |
```

I tried to use `concat` with `keep= 'First'` but I am afraid that if a have lot of data it will alterate the existing data in df1(I want to add only missing data based on **Number**).

Is there a better way of achieving this?
this how I tried to concat

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['Number'],keep='first')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `df1` and `df2` to set the index as column `Number` and use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = (
    df1.set_index('Number').combine_first(
        df2.set_index('Number')).reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
   Number    Name   Age
0     121    John  25.0
1     122     Sam  26.0
2     123  Andrew  28.0
```

Comment: Smart thinking. Thank you !

Comment: Of course. I needed to wait until I can accept answers :) Thank you again